# Pandas is installed but import pandas throws error

Tags: python, pandas

Some information about version i am using

```
pip -V
```

Result:

```
pip 6.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

Next:

```
python -c "import sys,pip;print(sys.version,pip,pip.__version__)"
```

Result:

```
('2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) \n[GCC 4.8.2]', <module 'pip' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.pyc'>, '1.5.4')
```

I have installed pandas by

```
sudo pip install pandas
sudo easy_install pandas
```

I can see pandas in my system using

```
pip list
```

Result

```
certifi (14.5.14)
nltk (3.0.2)
numpy (1.9.2)
pandas (0.16.1)
pip (6.1.1)
pyparsing (2.0.3)
python-dateutil (2.4.2)
pytz (2015.2)
setuptools (2.1)
six (1.9.0)
tornado (4.1)
```

But when I import it, it throws error

```
python

>>> import pandas
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Pandas is installed but why it is not working and how to make pandas work with my python interpreter

Comment: What operating system and what version(s) of python are you using?

Comment: ubutnu 14.4 and I have installed python 2.7 and python 3.4(Both)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the results of `pip -V` and `python -c "import sys,pip;print(sys.version,pip,pip.__version__)"` at the command line.  One possibility is that you've installed it into a different Python than you're running.

Comment: I had problems having both 2.7 and 3.4 when dealing with modules. But I'm on windows 8.1, not sure if Ubuntu will handle them better. Worth looking into tho.

Comment: Now that you've added the extra output, the problem is pretty obvious: `pip` currently points to the Python 3 version of pip, and `python` points to Python 2. So you have pandas installed for Python 3, and then you're trying to import in Python 2. You can specify which pip to use like: `sudo pip2 install pandas`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you expect your Python 2 and Python 3 installations to be in sync. The output from `pip -V` clearly displays that it is running on Python 3.4, and the output of `python -c "import sys,pip;print(sys.version,pip,pip.__version__)"` clearly indicates it is using Python 2.7 (look at the version number in the library path).

By contrast, here's the same thing using a current virtual environment on my development system.

```
(dojo) airhead-2:tools sholden$ pip -V
pip 1.5.6 from /Users/sholden/dojo/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
(dojo) airhead-2:tools sholden$ python -c "import sys,pip;print(sys.version,pip,pip.__version__)"
3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 17:50:17)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] <module 'pip' from '/Users/sholden/dojo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/__init__.py'> 1.5.6
```

You will see that the `which` command shows that `pip` and `python` both come from the same binary directory, and that the versions are matched.

```
(dojo) airhead-2:tools sholden$ which pip
 /Users/sholden/dojo/bin/pip
(dojo) airhead-2:tools sholden$ which python
/Users/sholden/dojo/bin/python
```

Virtual environments were invented to keep the dependencies of one project from leaking into other projects. I suggest you think about starting to use them.